# Why is there code autofilling my input box?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

This bug happens randomly and I'm hoping someone has run into this problem before.. It does not occur every time and I haven't found a reliable way to reproduce it. The only way to temporarily fix the problem has been to clear the browser cache. But it does eventually pop back up again. Because it's hard to reliably recreate this bug, it's hard to fix/diagnose so I need help. I double checked with those that ran into this bug and it isn't something they are entering into the form and being saved by the browser although as I've said, clearing the browser cache seems to temporarily fix the issue. Weird.

When the user clicks the input box the following text shows up inside it as an autofill option:

`,function(t){return f(t.value)?{required:!0}:null}`

user-form.component.html(username input):

```
<input
  autofocus="true"
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="username"
  id="user-form-username"
  type="text"
  >
```

This component uses the OnInit lifecycle hook. My ngOnInit() function calls the buildForm() function.

user-form.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'user-form',
  templateUrl: './user-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-form.component.scss']
})
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit {

  userForm: FormGroup;
  
  @Output() isFormDirty = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() submit = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() takeAction = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  // buildForm() function called from ngOnInit()
  // Maybe using validators wrong since bug occurs
  // towards the beginning of this components lifecycle?
  buildForm() {
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      'formName': ['userForm', Validators.required],
      'username': ['', Validators.required],
      'password': ['', Validators.required],
      'confirmPassword': ['', Validators.required],
      'fullName': ['', Validators.required],
      'email': ['', Validators.required],
      'role': ['', Validators.required],
      'state': ['active', Validators.required],
      'authType': ['local', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  // This function occurs when the form is submitted.
  // Included this function in this SO question
  // so the full lifecycle of the FormGroup is here.
  resetForm() {
    this.userForm.reset({
      'formName': ['userForm', Validators.required],
      'username': ['', Validators.required],
      'password': ['', Validators.required],
      'confirmPassword': ['', Validators.required],
      'fullName': ['', Validators.required],
      'email': ['', Validators.required],
      'role': ['', Validators.required],
      'state': ['active', Validators.required],
      'authType': ['local', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  // This is the function that submits the form data and
  // resets the form.
  submitForm() {
    this.submit.emit(this.userForm.value);
    this.resetForm();
    this.dirty = false;
    this.isFormDirty.emit(false);
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    // Custom warnings to display warnings in html code
    this.warning = {
      username: false,
      usernameIllegalChars: false,
      password: false,
      confirmPassword: false,
      fullName: false,
      email: false,
      role: false
    };
    
    // Call to buildForm function to build the FormGroup using FormBuilder
    this.buildForm();

    // Subscribing to default empty form values to check if form is dirty
    // or has information that should be saved. Used to warn user they 
    // have unsaved changes if they try to navigate away without saving.
    this.userForm.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {
      if (form.username !== '' || form.password !== '' || form.confirmPassword !== '' 
          || form.fullName !== '' || form.email !== '' || form.role !== '' 
          || form.state !== 'active' || form.authType !== 'local') {
        if (this.dirty === false) {
          this.dirty = true;
          this.isFormDirty.emit(true);
        }
      } else {
        this.dirty = false;
        this.isFormDirty.emit(false);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Turn off form autocompletion, `autocomplete="off"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "reset" should be **without** the validators

```
this.userForm.reset({
      'formName': 'userForm',
      'username': ''
      'password': ''
       ...
    });
```

NOTE: If in the object you pass, you omit one property, this property becomes null
See in the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset) that you should pass as argument an object with the properties

Comment: The code autofill in my input makes a lot more sense now. Thank you. Do you recommend turning autocomplete off on my form inputs like the comment reply to my question suggests? I realize now this would have hidden the bug that was occurring. I accepted your answer to the question but I don't have enough reputation to upvote you yet. Sorry.